# Pass parameter in an already opened form in C#

Tags: c#

I want to pass a parameter to the textbox. I have the following code and it is passing the parameter but not the way I want.
My main form in already open and I want to pass the parameter from my search form. when I do with the code below it opens mt 1 more main form and the parameter is shown in there. I want to by able to show in the opened main form.

When I erase frmMain.Show(); nothing happens.

```
Main frmMain = new Main();
artikal = "TEST TEST";

frmMain.ed_artiakal.Text = artikal;
frmMain.Show();
```

any suggestions?

Comment: You need to have a reference to the original form in your search form. You could either pass it via constructor to the search-form or by overloading `Show`/`ShowDialog` with the `Main`-form as parameter.

Comment: You need either a reference to the original form or (better) an event that the original form can attach to to get the data - that way you don't couple the two forms together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem in the following way.

On my Search Form I created a public string and when I showed the form I referenced to that string in my case GetItemCode.

The key here was to use ShowDialog() and not to use Show().

**SEARCH FORM**

```
Search frmSearch = new Search();
frmSearch.ShowDialog();

ed_artiakal.Text = frmSearch.GetItemCode;
```

**MAIN FORM**

```
public string GetItemCode
        {
            get { return Artikal; }
        }
```

Now when I close the search form the value is shown in the TextBox on my main form.

Thanks for your answers and comments!

Answer (score 2):

You have many variants to solve your problem.

**Option 1**
Define and use custom event.

Search form code:

```
public event EventHandler ArtikalTextChanged;

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (ArtikalTextChanged != null)
         ArtikalTextChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Main form code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Search search = new Search();
    search.ArtikalTextChanged += OnArtikalTextChanged;
    search.Show();
}

private void OnArtikalTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{         
    this.ed_artiakal.Text = (sender as Search).textBox1.Text;
}
```

Don't forget to make textBox1 of Search form public.

**Option 2**
Get instance of your main form in search form:

Search form code:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var mainForm = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Main>().FirstOrDefault();
    mainForm.ed_artiakal.Text = textBox1.Text;
}
```

Main form code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Search search = new Search();
    search.Show();
}
```

Don't forget to make ed_artiakal control public in your Main form.

**Option 3**
Share data between forms (recommend)
But if you application is large and you want to make it scaleable and flexible I recommend you to use data-binding technique to share data between forms without coupling them. You can read more at articles: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h974h4y2(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: You forgot Option 4, "pass the `MainForm` instance to the search form". That said, IMHO your Option 1 is really the better idea; the search form should be general purpose, without specific references to `MainForm`. The one thing I would change is to _not_ expose the entire `textBox1` object, but rather to expose its `Text` property as a property of the search form itself.